# sick_tim unable to connect to laserscanner

Tags: ros, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to start the sick_tim package, but it can't connect to the TiM Laserscanner.
With Windows and SOPAS ET I can config the scanner.
The IP is set to 169.254.8.76 and the Subnetmask to 255.255.0.0
With Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro I can ping the scanner but with ROS I can't connect.

Here the console output:

```
roslaunch sick_tim sick_tim551_2050001.launch
... logging to /home/youbot/.ros/log/e93740a6-eac1-11e5-8203-000bab452ad7/roslaunch-youbot-mobile-24935.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://youbot-mobile:60044/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /sick_tim551_2050001/hostname
 * /sick_tim551_2050001/port
 * /sick_tim551_2050001/timelimit

NODES
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    sick_tim551_2050001 (sick_tim/sick_tim551_2050001)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [24956]
process[sick_tim551_2050001-2]: started with pid [24974]
[ INFO] [1458055448.586484076]: Waiting 5 seconds for device to connect.
[ERROR] [1458055448.587026044]: Failed to connect to 169.254.8.76:2112
[FATAL] [1458055448.587163911]: Could not connect to host 169.254.8.76:2112
[FATAL] [1458055448.587592177]: Failed to init device: 1
[ERROR] [1458055448.588381034]: write error for command: sEN LMDscandata 0

SOPAS - Error stopping streaming scan data!
sick_tim driver exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229122/sick_tim-unable-to-connect-to-laserscanner/) by [RKT](https://answers.ros.org/users/26282/rkt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to be clear: You set the scanner IP to 169.254.8.76, right? What did you set your computer's IP to? If you also used 169.254.8.76, you weren't pinging the scanner, you were pinging yourself. Try something else in the 169.254.8.* range, like 169.254.8.42 . Also see [sick_tim #34](https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/issues/34).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ali_Mohamed](https://answers.ros.org/users/150995/ali_mohamed/) on 2023-05-24**:
yup, works for me.